# Python get character code in different encoding?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-codes

Given a character code as integer number in one encoding, how can you get the character code in, say, utf-8 and again as integer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), so I'll assume you really meant "Unicode code point". Use `chr()` to convert the character code to a character, decode it, and use `ord()` to get the code point.

```
>>> ord(chr(145).decode('koi8-r'))
9618
```

Comment: `chr() arg not in range(256)` for 'shift_jisx0213'

Comment: In Python 2, `chr` only supports ASCII, so only numbers in the `[0..255]` range. Use `unichr` instead for Unicode support.

Comment: Hmm `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u8140' in position 0
: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: `chr(145)` is probably equivalent to `unichr(145).encode('latin1')` on Python 2 if the input is in `range(256)`. There is no `unichr` on Python 3, it is renamed to `chr`. It is usually a hack to fix the input if you need: `reinterpreted = unistr.encode(one_encoding).decode(another_encoding)`

Answer (score 12):

You can only map an "integer number" from one encoding to another if they are both *single-byte* encodings.

Here's an example using "iso-8859-15" and "cp1252" (aka "ANSI"):

```
>>> s = u'€'
>>> s.encode('iso-8859-15')
'\xa4'
>>> s.encode('cp1252')
'\x80'
>>> ord(s.encode('cp1252'))
128
>>> ord(s.encode('iso-8859-15'))
164
```

Note that `ord` is here being used to get the ordinal number of the *encoded byte*. Using `ord` on the original unicode string would give its *unicode code point*:

```
>>> ord(s)
8364
```

The reverse operation to `ord` can be done using either `chr` (for codes in the range `0` to `127`) or `unichr` (for codes in the range `0` to `sys.maxunicode`):

```
>>> print chr(65)
A
>>> print unichr(8364)
€
```

For multi-byte encodings, a simple "integer number" mapping is usually not possible.

Here's the same example as above, but using "iso-8859-15" and "utf-8":

```
>>> s = u'€'
>>> s.encode('iso-8859-15')
'\xa4'
>>> s.encode('utf-8')
'\xe2\x82\xac'
>>> [ord(c) for c in s.encode('iso-8859-15')]
[164]
>>> [ord(c) for c in s.encode('utf-8')]
[226, 130, 172]
```

The "utf-8" encoding uses three bytes to encode the same character, so a one-to-one mapping is not possible. Having said that, many encodings (including "utf-8") are designed to be ASCII-compatible, so a mapping *is* usually possible for codes in the range 0-127 (but only trivially so, because the code will always be the same).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how the encode/decode dance works:

```
>>> s = b'd\x06'             # perhaps start with bytes encoded in utf-16
>>> map(ord, s)              # show those bytes as integers
[100, 6]
>>> u = s.decode('utf-16')   # turn the bytes into unicode
>>> print u                  # show what the character looks like
٤
>>> print ord(u)             # show the unicode code point as an integer
1636
>>> t = u.encode('utf-8')    # turn the unicode into bytes with a different encoding
>>> map(ord, t)              # show that encoding as integers
[217, 164]
```

Hope this helps :-)

If you need to construct the unicode directly from an integer, use *[unichr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unichr)*:

```
>>> u = unichr(1636)
>>> print u
٤
```