# Encoding a unicode string to utf-8 and getting question marks

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

System:

```
Python 2.7.5 , IPython 2.3.1 , OSX terminal (local), sys.stdout.encoding : 'UTF-8'
(venv) toz$ locale LANG="en_US.UTF-8" LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8" LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8" LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8" LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8" LC_ALL= –
```

I am expecting both commands print the same but the latter prints question marks for ord(c)>128. Why is that? How can I encode this unicode string and iterate through without getting the question marks?

```
In [77]: for c in u'!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~’”“': print c.encode('utf-8'),
! " # % ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ ’ ” “

In [78]: for c in u'!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~’”“'.encode('utf-8'): print c,
! " # % ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
```

Lets print the ord values:

```
In [92]: for c in u'!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~’”“': print c.encode('utf-8'),ord(c),
! 33 " 34 # 35 % 37 ' 39 ( 40 ) 41 * 42 + 43 , 44 - 45 . 46 / 47 : 58 ; 59 < 60 = 61 > 62 ? 63 @ 64 [ 91 \ 92 ] 93 ^ 94 _ 95 ` 96 { 123 | 124 } 125 ~ 126 ’ 8217 ” 8221 “ 8220

In [93]: for c in u'!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~’”“': print c.encode('utf-8'),ord(c.encode('utf-8')),
! 33 " 34 # 35 % 37 ' 39 ( 40 ) 41 * 42 + 43 , 44 - 45 . 46 / 47 : 58 ; 59 < 60 = 61 > 62 ? 63 @ 64 [ 91 \ 92 ] 93 ^ 94 _ 95 ` 96 { 123 | 124 } 125 ~ 126 ’---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-1eb3985b825b> in <module>()
----> 1 for c in u'!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~’”“': print c.encode('utf-8'),ord(c.encode('utf-8')),

TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 3 found
```

I can relate this length of three to nine question marks as well as the required (three) bytes for each of the three non-ascii characters.

Comment: Start `ipython notebook` to get the web-interface and avoid Unicode + Windows console issues. Print Unicode (remove  `.encode('utf-8')`) in this case.

Comment: If you are not on Windows; to fix the output, just remove `.encode('utf-8')` (print Unicode directly).

Comment: I'm on OSX and got the same output (i.e. question marks) from ipython notebook as well.

Comment: have you dropped `.encode('utf-8')` as I said? Add `assert type(c) == unicode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `encode` a string, it converts from Unicode characters to bytes. Each character can become a variable number of bytes. It appears your console prints any bytes outside of the ASCII range of 0-127 as a question mark.

```
>>> for c in u'!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~’”“': print len(c.encode('utf-8')),

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3


>>> for c in u'!"#%\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~’”“'.encode('utf-8'): print c,ord(c),

! 33 " 34 # 35 % 37 ' 39 ( 40 ) 41 * 42 + 43 , 44 - 45 . 46 / 47 : 58 ; 59 < 60 = 61 > 62 ? 63 @ 64 [ 91 \ 92 ] 93 ^ 94 _ 95 ` 96 { 123 | 124 } 125 ~ 126 â 226 ﾀ 128 ﾙ 153 â 226 ﾀ 128 ﾝ 157 â 226 ﾀ 128 ﾜ 156
```

The reason you get question marks is that you've broken up the UTF-8 sequences, and each byte of the sequence isn't a valid character *by itself*. Those invalid characters are displayed as question marks.

As you can see, my console (Python 2.7.5's IDLE) doesn't print question marks but substitutes incorrect characters instead.

Comment: it should print `3` instead `2`. I've copy-pasted the characters from your answer `u'’”“'` they are `u'\u2019\u201d\u201c'`. Any other value is the issue with your environment. [U+0092](http://codepoints.net/U+0092), etc are control characters unrelated to the quotes.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I get the same result on two different PCs, both running Windows 7, copying from Chrome and pasting into the Python 2.7 IDLE console.

Comment: You can check whether It is a Windows clipboard corrupts the value (unlikely) or IDLE while sending them to a child process: `print repr(u'\u2019\u201d\u201c'), u'\u2019\u201d\u201c'`. If IDLE on Python 2 supports it; try to start it using "same/single process" mode.

Comment: `u'\u2019'.encode('cp1252').decode('latin1') == u'\x92'`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian the problem is with Idle, if I read the characters directly from the clipboard I get the right values.

Comment: If it is reproducable on Python 2.7.9; could your [submit a bug report](http://bugs.python.org/)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian it's already fixed in Python 3.2. I've had other problems with Unicode input in Idle 2.7, I've just about given up.

Comment: As far as I know,  Python 2.7 bugs could be fixed if you report it.

Comment: "It appears your console prints any bytes outside of the ASCII range of 0-127 as a question mark." Yes, it is obvious but I still don't know why and how to fix? Every setting appears to be UTF-8 as I commented below @bav's answer.

Comment: @oztalha I've updated my answer with the final piece of the puzzle. The way to fix it is to stop trying to print out each of the UTF-8 bytes as if it were a character, because it isn't.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks. Now I know why I got it also thanks to this  [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8609051/1054154).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian it has been reported multiple times, but nobody can convince the devs that it's a real or solvable issue. See e.g. http://bugs.python.org/issue17348 and http://bugs.python.org/issue15809.

Comment: @MarkRansom: yes. the issues are the same: clipboard correctly passes `u'\u2019'` character, IDLE encodes it to cp1252 (Python source encoding on your machine in IDLE -- it should be the same as Windows codepage) as if you've typed it manually, something (`compile()` function?) (I don't understand why [pep-0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) is mentioned) uses latin1 encoding. Do you see `ord(u'€') == 128` on your machine? What value do you get `ord(u'\u20ac')`? I think it is worth to leave a message on http://bugs.python.org/issue15809 (the issue is in "patch review" stage).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I finally got motivated to find my own answer to the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28060419/5987

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have "C" locale. You can check it with `locale` shell command.
Or you can run ipython with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ipython` (for bash/sh/etc)

Comment: It appears not to be related to locale: (venv) toz$ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: I guess this is a ssh session. Then problem is in settings of your terminal. You use putty?

Comment: Do you use Terminal.app? Try iTerm2. It's very interesting issue.

Comment: Yes, regular terminal. I got the same result in notebook as well: [screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/037484q935)

Comment: Last guess. What value has sys.stdout.encoding?

Comment: In [2]: sys.stdout.encoding
Out[2]: 'UTF-8'

Comment: I'm a dumb-dumb. I though that first expression also outputs question marks somehow. @MarkRansom give a correct answer. Your terminal font has no latin symbols with umlauts.